# SVG Mask Transparent Circle - Show only text without yellow background

Tags: javascript, html, image, svg, mask

Hello I'm new to svg masks and I have the following problem:

The circle is a svg mask which follows the cursor over the image.
Behind the image is another image with a tagcloud which is an png with transparent background.

Now I just want to see the text from the image behind WITHOUT the yellow
background from the website. Is this possible? I would be very happy if someone could help me.

Here is my code from the demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/ayyuqrw4/1/

```
    <svg>
        <defs>
            <mask id="cursorMask" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskContentUtils="objectBoundingBox">
                <g>
                    <rect x="0" y="0" width="1600" height="700" fill="#FFFFFF" />
                    <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="60" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="black" fill-opacity="1" />
                </g>
            </mask>
        </defs>
        <image width="1600" height="700" xlink:href="https://41.media.tumblr.com/e91c999c320c29a28053c6a933da1e81/tumblr_mkjnibe1xH1s9yt1no1_500.png" />
        <image width="1600" height="700" xlink:href="http://www.liftopia.com/media/product/275/102102_Ski-Banff-Lake-Louise-Sunshine-1-Day-Lift-Tickets.jpg" />
    </svg>

var img = document.getElementsByTagName("image")[1];
var imgPos = img.getBoundingClientRect();
var imgX = imgPos.left;
var imgY = imgPos.top;
var rect = document.getElementsByTagName("circle")[0];
var rectHalfWidth = rect.getAttribute("width") / 2;
var rectHalfHeight = rect.getAttribute("height") / 2;
img.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
    rect.setAttribute("cx", e.clientX - imgX - rectHalfWidth);
    rect.setAttribute("cy", e.clientY - imgY - rectHalfHeight);
}, false);

body {
    background-color: yellow;
}

svg {
    width: 1600px;
    height: 700px;
}
image:hover {
    mask: url("#cursorMask");
}
```

And here is what I want:

[Final Result](http://postimg.org/image/stnupcxdd/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick the original image behind everything.

Note how I've adjusted your getElementsByTagName to fit because I'm lazy but it would be better if you gave the image you want to select an id and converted to getElementById.

```js
var img = document.getElementsByTagName("image")[2];
var imgPos = img.getBoundingClientRect();
var imgX = imgPos.left;
var imgY = imgPos.top;
var rect = document.getElementsByTagName("circle")[0];
var rectHalfWidth = rect.getAttribute("width") / 2;
var rectHalfHeight = rect.getAttribute("height") / 2;
img.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
    rect.setAttribute("cx", e.clientX - imgX - rectHalfWidth);
    rect.setAttribute("cy", e.clientY - imgY - rectHalfHeight);
}, false);
```

```css
body {
    background-color: yellow;
}

svg {
    width: 1600px;
    height: 700px;
}
image:hover {
    mask: url("#cursorMask");
}
```

```html
    <svg>
        <defs>
            <mask id="cursorMask" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskContentUtils="objectBoundingBox">
                <g>
                    <rect x="0" y="0" width="1600" height="700" fill="#FFFFFF" />
                    <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="60" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="black" fill-opacity="1" />
                </g>
            </mask>
        </defs>
        <image width="1600" height="700" xlink:href="http://www.liftopia.com/media/product/275/102102_Ski-Banff-Lake-Louise-Sunshine-1-Day-Lift-Tickets.jpg" />
        <image width="1600" height="700" xlink:href="https://41.media.tumblr.com/e91c999c320c29a28053c6a933da1e81/tumblr_mkjnibe1xH1s9yt1no1_500.png" />
        <image width="1600" height="700" xlink:href="http://www.liftopia.com/media/product/275/102102_Ski-Banff-Lake-Louise-Sunshine-1-Day-Lift-Tickets.jpg" />
    </svg>
```

Comment: You beat me  from a few seconds. Here's the corresponding jsfiddle, same solution: https://jsfiddle.net/ayyuqrw4/4/